# DigitalOcean Spaces not working with AWS SDK PHP

Tags: laravel, amazon-s3, digital-ocean, spaces

I got laravel application and want to use DigitalOcean spaces.

It's working for single file upload or download.

But when i try to use laravel `Storage::disk('database-backups')->allFiles('')`

i get this error:

```
Error executing "ListObjects" on "https://bucket-staging.ams3.digitaloceanspaces.com/database-backups?prefix=%2F&max-keys=1&encoding-type=url"; AWS HTTP error: Client error: `
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><Error><Code>NoSuchKey</Code><BucketName>bucket-staging</BucketName><RequestId>tx00 (truncated...)
 NoSuchKey (client):
```

Im using `"league/flysystem-aws-s3-v3": "~1.0"` for laravel disk.